# Move working page Joomla 2.5 to localhost

Tags: php, apache, joomla

I have a working Joomla page that would like to move to localhost.
Whenever I try to run the folder in localhost(MAMP), 
for example: **localhost/mysite**. the localhost becomes http://www.localhost/. And the index.php does not even run.
I checked the following:

- configuration.php
- apache rewrite module
- dowloaded a new Joomla(which works on MAMP) to compare configuration files (they seem fine)
- php and apache logs no errors

so if it is not php or apache then what might be the problem?

This page has been created by someone else by the way!

thanks in advance for any help provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename the htaccess file OR check under htaccess file if some rewrite condition for URL change is written or not and then if its thr, do operation to the readwrite rule.

Let me know if it works for you or not.